# Find the parent CSS selector from Child using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I want to find the parent selector of any child selector using JavaScript or jQuery. Here is example code of a static HTML page:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Here `class box` and `class box-2` are inside of an element with an ID of `container`.

Let's say I need to find the CSS selector for some case. Now, in this case it's small example. But, in case of heavy code, I want to find the parent selector of `box` or `box-2` which is `container`. It makes the process easy and flexible rather than finding manually from google developer console (I am using chrome).

Comment: Take a look at this jQuery function https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: The CSS selector for an element is ambiguous: There are many possible selectors matching the same element, so you cannot just ask for *the selector*. Also, if you have a selector, there is no guarantee it won't match any other elements...

Comment: The only selector which is guaranteed to be unique (in a well-formed document) is "id".

Comment: In jQuery, the selector would be: `'div:has(.box):has(.box-2)'`, now your question is quite ambiguous and i'm not sure this is what you are expecting

Comment: @A.Wolff Question is clear. What's the class for the parent? So, `$(this).closest("div").closest("div").attr("class");` would be the answer. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar In posted HTML markup, i don't see any element being parent of `.box` and `.box-2` getting any class

Comment: Please make up your mind which answer you want to accept. A question can only have one accepted answer at a time. If you cannot decide, you are free to not accept any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*CSS selector for parent*

I would answer that there is not css selector available for parent element.

But you can use js/jQuery to get the parent element of it. like this in jQuery:

```
var cont = $('.box').siblings('.box-2').parent();
```

with `.filter()`:

```
var cont = $('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('.box').length && $(this).find('.box-2').length;
});
```

Comment: You surely want to check for `length` of matched sets: `return $(this).find('.box').length && $(this).find('.box-2').length;`

Comment: Ohh missed it @A.Wolff. That's why I like you so much. Thnx.

Comment: Your idea of using `$('.box').siblings('.box-2').parent()` is quite clever indeed  :)

Comment: Coming from you! Loved it. Actually you are the mentor. Learnt so many tricks from your answers. Thank once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in two ways. If you don't know the parent's class, and know the tag, you can do this:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".box, .box-2").html(function () {
    return "My parent's class is: " + $(this).closest("div").closest("div").attr("class");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Something is wrong here... There shouldn't be any element with a class `box` or `box-2` which is a parent for another element in this example.

Comment: Looks like in this case, instead of `$(this).closest("div").closest("div")` you should use: `.closest('div[class]')`

Comment: @A.Wolff For some reason, `.closest("div")` shows the current parent. Yes, I should have used that, but closest parent is what OP's need. `:P` Solved for the need, even though a bit hacky.

Comment: In fact sorry, it shouldn't be `.closest('div[class]')` but `.parents('div[class]').first()`, my bad

Comment: This is devil's work `:S` It doesn't matter how many `.closest("div")` you chain. Still shows the same output. How? `o.O`

Comment: @DarthBatuKhan Devil's Work. True. `:P`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('.box-2').parent();
```

Comment: A little explanation or documentation reference would be helpful.